# Matching 1's from a vector to list elements in R?

Tags: r

```
pset[[1]]="000100" "100110" "001000" "100000" "100001" "100010"
```

```
true="000110"
```

I want to match only 1's from true to pset[[1]].
For example: true has 1 at digit 4 and 5 and pset[[1]] has second element which has 1 at digit 4 and 5.

So I should get answer as 1.

Can anyone help me out with this.
I know match command in R but it matches all digits. However, I am only interested in 1's

Comment: why 1 as the answer?

Comment: Because I was raising a counter if that happens as part of my code. that is why 1 was the answer. Thanks for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could subtract each digit after `strsplit` and check if any is less than zero.

```
sapply(pset, \(x) {
  !any(do.call(`-`, lapply(strsplit(cbind(true, x), ''), as.numeric)) < 0)
}, USE.NAMES=FALSE) |> which()
# [1] 1
```

---

*Data:*

```
pset <- c("000100", "100110", "001000", "100000", "100001", "100010")
true <- "000110"
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting but again it is matching 0's also , i think because in the same question if true="001110" and pset is same . The answer should be 0 but it is not?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite convoluted and perhaps suboptimal, but here you go:

1. Turn your digit strings into arrays of booleans

```
to_bool <- function(s) strsplit(s, "")[[1]] == "1"
true_bool = to_bool(true)
pset_bool = lapply(pset, to_bool)
```

2. Your condition is satisfied when the AND of pset_bool and true_bool (which represents the digits that are true in both strings) is identical to true_bool (meaning, all the digits that are true in true_bool were not false in pset_bool, or the AND would have returned false)

```
sapply(pset_bool, function(b) all((b & true_bool) == true_bool))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Glad it helped you (onyambu's answer would also work, I think, as it does the same more efficiently). You can select the checkmark next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: ```pset[[1]]="000100" "100110" "101101" "101111" "100001" "100010"```   ```true="100110"``` How about if I want to match 1's again but from each vector in pset. So, it is matching first , fourth and fifth position of true with each in pset and the answer should be                ```1 3 2 3 1 2``` (i.e. count of matching 1's only)

Comment: @PRITI you can ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

These are bitwise operations dealing with binary numbers.\

You could do:

```
sum(sapply(pset, function(x) rawToChar(charToRaw(x)&charToRaw(true)))==true)
[1] 1
```